# Carrierwave only saves image as tmp in Production-env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, carrierwave

Spent the whole daying trying to get this to work. Carrierwaves and my fileuploads works fine when doing on the development/local-computer, but when trying on my server with ENV:Production and deploying through Capistrano the files only get saved in the uploads/tmp/ and not as stated in my image_uploader.

```
 def store_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

I have tried several things suggested when I searced but nothing have solved this problem.

Furthermore my form/post does not forward me but I stay on the same page as I uploaded, which doesnt happen when in development/local.

Here is some parts my deploy.rb that I thought would solve the problem:

```
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs) + %w{public/uploads}
```

`task :symlink_uploads do
     run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/uploads  #{release_path}/public/uploads"
   end`

```
 after :restart, :seed_roles, :symlink_uploads
```

Edit question: 
Do I have to move pictures being uploaded from tmp to where I want them to be stored?

Comment: Please post `config/initializers/carrierwave.rb`

Comment: I have none atm. In my image_uploader I have  storage :file. What to do?

Comment: what is defined in cache_dir

Comment: Where can i find this? I guess nothing..? Thx for helping

Answer (score 0):

please do the following

and in set up

**config/initializers/carrierwave.rb**

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.root = Rails.root
end
```

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/how-to:-secure-upload

Here you do not require to change  store_dir

if you want to change the random hex file name

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Create-random-and-unique-filenames-for-all-versioned-files

put the below code in your uploader

```
def filename
     "#{secure_token(10)}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
  end

  protected
  def secure_token(length=16)
    var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
    model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.hex(length/2))
  end
```

Hope it will solve the problem

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but the problem still remains, the file is saved in uploads/tmp/1432906113-19521-2715/thumb_elg.jpg and not stored.

Comment: As a mather of facts, this makes it store it in public/public/

Comment: Solved the problem with public/public but concerning this you are linking: Is that really the answer to what I am looking for? My files are saved in /uploads/tmp and not where it should. How do I move them or make them getting saved in the right directory?

Comment: What Im saying is that this linkes are for not saving them in public or changing the names, which is totally fine for me.

Comment: If I change the config.root to Rails.root I dont have permissions to go into "public/uploads.."